# How to define a command that produces a different savebox depending on the argument

Tags: macros, boxes

I'd like to define a sequence of saveboxes `\fooA`, `\fooB`, etcetera, in a style file and introduce a command like

`\newcommand{\foo}[1]{....}`

which produces `\usebox{\fooA}` if the argument of `\foo` is 1, `\usebox{\fooB}` if the argument of `\foo` is 2, etcetera.

There must be a simple way of implementing this, but I'm out of my depth.

Thanks!

Comment: The saveboxes have been already declared, I assume?

Comment: yes, they have indeed

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This uses a counter to get the quick 'translation' from number to character. However, this is a quick-and-dirty usage, as it does not check for the maximum number possible (i.e. 26)

In addition, there should be check whether the box name `\fooA` etc. exists at all.

The box command `\foo` is created inside using `\csname foo\Alph{boxcounter}\endsname`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}%
\usepackage{blindtext}

\newsavebox{\fooA}

\newsavebox{\fooB}



\newcounter{boxcounter}

\newcommand{\foo}[1]{%
  \setcounter{boxcounter}{#1}%
  \usebox{\csname foo\Alph{boxcounter}\endcsname}
}%


\savebox{\fooA}{\textcolor{red}{\blindtext}}
\savebox{\fooB}{\textcolor{blue}{\blindtext}}



\begin{document}

\noindent\foo{1}\par

\noindent\foo{2}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @ChristianHupfer The only difference was that you called your counter `boxcounter`, whereas I called mine `boxnum`.  Great minds think alike!

Comment: The code `\usebox{\csname foo\@Alph{#1}\endcsname}` doesn't require a counter. Remember `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` around the definition of `\foo`. However it can go very wrong when Babel for Spanish is used and the value is high.

Comment: @egreg: That's so ... fundamental ;-)

Answer (score 5):

Using `\Alph` is safe only when `babel` is not used. With some languages `\Alph` is redefined for accommodating different alphabets; think to Czech where the alphabet order is

```
A B C Č D E F G H CH I ...
```

and `\foo{4}` would definitely not work in this context.

You probably are sticking to ASCII and, in order to have correct results independently of `babel` you can use an old trick of the trade:

```
\newcommand{\foo}[1]{%
  \begingroup\lccode`?=\dimexpr64+#1\relax % the code for A is 65
  \lowercase{\endgroup\usebox{\csname foo?\endcsname}}
}
```

This exploits the fact that you're prefixing the box names by `foo` which is lowercase. I'll show a solution that's independent of this.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\allocateboxes}[2]{% #1 = prefix, #2 = list of letters to be used
  \expandafter\newcommand\csname #1\endcsname[1]{%
    \usebox{\csname JPi@box@##1@\endcsname}%
  }%
  \count@=\z@
  \@for\next:=#2\do{%
    \advance\count@\@ne
    \expandafter\newsavebox\csname #1\next\endcsname
    \expandafter\edef\csname JPi@box@\the\count@ @\endcsname{%
      \expandafter\noexpand\csname #1\next\endcsname
    }%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\allocateboxes{Foo}{A,B}

\savebox{\FooA}{\textcolor{red}{This is box A}}
\savebox{\FooB}{\textcolor{blue}{This is box B}}

\begin{document}

\noindent\Foo{1}\par

\noindent\Foo{2}

\end{document}
```

[image]